# Kubenetes new Pods/Deployments/Resources stuck in pending state forever without error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I have a local Kubernetes cluster setup using kubeadm. Everything was working fine a few days back but now I've got a strange problem.

Whenever I add new resources be it a deployment or pod, it never gets scheduled and is forever stuck in Pending state without any error. Please let me know if you anyone has any idea how to fix this issue or even debug for that matter.

I'm pasting output of some of the commands I think might be useful, let me know if you need any additional information

•  kubectl get cs

```
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE                         ERROR
scheduler            Healthy   ok
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true","reason":""}
```

• kubectl get nodes -o wide

```
NAME              STATUS   ROLES           AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
in-dt-dckr-ldr1   Ready    control-plane   386d   v1.25.2   10.64.1.98    <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS   5.15.0-58-generic   containerd://1.6.8
in-dt-dckr-ldr2   Ready    <none>          386d   v1.25.2   10.64.1.190   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS   5.15.0-58-generic   containerd://1.6.8
in-dt-dckr-wrk1   Ready    worker          386d   v1.25.2   10.64.1.232   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS   5.15.0-58-generic   containerd://1.6.8
```

•  kubectl describe node in-dt-dckr-wrk1

```
Name:               in-dt-dckr-wrk1
Roles:              worker
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=in-dt-dckr-wrk1
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/worker=worker
Annotations:        csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"csi.tigera.io":"in-dt-dckr-wrk1"}
                    kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4Address: 10.64.1.232/22
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4VXLANTunnelAddr: 192.168.137.192
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 13 Oct 2022 01:04:07 +0530
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  in-dt-dckr-wrk1
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Fri, 03 Nov 2023 08:57:17 +0530
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Sat, 21 Jan 2023 19:29:25 +0530   Sat, 21 Jan 2023 19:29:25 +0530   CalicoIsUp                   Calico is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       False   Fri, 03 Nov 2023 08:53:02 +0530   Sat, 21 Jan 2023 19:28:44 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Fri, 03 Nov 2023 08:53:02 +0530   Sat, 21 Jan 2023 19:28:44 +0530   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Fri, 03 Nov 2023 08:53:02 +0530   Sat, 21 Jan 2023 19:28:44 +0530   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Fri, 03 Nov 2023 08:53:02 +0530   Sat, 21 Jan 2023 19:28:44 +0530   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.64.1.232
  Hostname:    in-dt-dckr-wrk1
Capacity:
  cpu:                8
  ephemeral-storage:  959786032Ki
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             8023576Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                8
  ephemeral-storage:  884538805627
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             7921176Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 9e7f87693fba4ce5b5cffd58e27c4b5e
  System UUID:                4c4c4544-0032-5910-804e-b3c04f595831
  Boot ID:                    8c6f8a8c-0acc-4ac9-86df-36867df44d8f
  Kernel Version:             5.15.0-58-generic
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  containerd://1.6.8
  Kubelet Version:            v1.25.2
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.25.2
PodCIDR:                      192.168.1.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     192.168.1.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (18 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  buildninja                  bn-agent1-6f484b8894-qr88p                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         52d
  buildninja                  bn-agent2-67b6859f58-zg6kc                  0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         52d
  calico-apiserver            calico-apiserver-978f5784c-77gss            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         346d
  calico-system               calico-kube-controllers-6fdfb4dfdc-rfbsr    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         346d
  calico-system               calico-node-4gxvn                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         386d
  calico-system               calico-typha-5cd5cbc888-mcqfh               0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         386d
  calico-system               csi-node-driver-zr5lc                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         386d
  db                          mongodb-cc47dc8b8-wwszq                     0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         178d
  db                          postgres-79f797b96c-vhswc                   0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         285d
  docker-registry             gci-docker-registry-644799b4b7-q8wbl        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         283d
  kube-system                 coredns-5fcc5bdd47-b6w88                    100m (1%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (2%)     283d
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-zjp4z                            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         386d
  kube-system                 metrics-server-5db9b4b966-8gqgk             100m (1%)     0 (0%)      200Mi (2%)       0 (0%)         386d
  tigera-operator             tigera-operator-6675dc47f4-z9jtx            0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         386d
  utils                       web-sample-ff4d6596-hmtw6                   0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         170d
  utils                       wiki-server-86f49bd4c4-4drdr                0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         182d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                200m (2%)   0 (0%)
  memory             270Mi (3%)  170Mi (2%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

• kubectl describe po nginx

```
Name:             nginx
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             <none>
Labels:           run=nginx
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Pending
IP:
IPs:              <none>
Containers:
  nginx:
    Image:        nginx
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-lg45r (ro)
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-lg45r:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

I found a similar case but no resolutions there too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55310076/pods-are-in-pending-state

**Update 1**
Adding output for journalctl

•  sudo journalctl -u kubelet -f

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2022-04-22 10:32:53 IST. --
Nov 01 14:18:45 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: I1101 14:18:45.802594 3279607 request.go:682] Waited for 1.137588349s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: POST:https://10.64.1.98:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods
Nov 01 14:18:45 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:45.845718 3279607 kubelet.go:1712] "Failed creating a mirror pod for" err="pods \"etcd-in-dt-dckr-ldr1\" already exists" pod="kube-system/etcd-in-dt-dckr-ldr1"
Nov 01 14:18:46 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:46.123742 3279607 configmap.go:197] Couldn't get configMap kube-system/kube-proxy: failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
Nov 01 14:18:46 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:46.123782 3279607 configmap.go:197] Couldn't get configMap calico-system/tigera-ca-bundle: failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
Nov 01 14:18:46 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:46.123870 3279607 nestedpendingoperations.go:348] Operation for "{volumeName:kubernetes.io/configmap/61a2bf9a-a4cb-49d8-8b63-de7a82841a55-kube-proxy podName:61a2bf9a-a4cb-49d8-8b63-de7a82841a55 nodeName:}" failed. No retries permitted until 2023-11-01 14:18:46.62383261 +0530 IST m=+3.132668643 (durationBeforeRetry 500ms). Error: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "kube-proxy" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/configmap/61a2bf9a-a4cb-49d8-8b63-de7a82841a55-kube-proxy") pod "kube-proxy-6ghjb" (UID: "61a2bf9a-a4cb-49d8-8b63-de7a82841a55") : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
Nov 01 14:18:46 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:46.123907 3279607 nestedpendingoperations.go:348] Operation for "{volumeName:kubernetes.io/configmap/43736256-5241-46c4-b403-85db6d1d4d52-tigera-ca-bundle podName:43736256-5241-46c4-b403-85db6d1d4d52 nodeName:}" failed. No retries permitted until 2023-11-01 14:18:46.623887546 +0530 IST m=+3.132723570 (durationBeforeRetry 500ms). Error: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "tigera-ca-bundle" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/configmap/43736256-5241-46c4-b403-85db6d1d4d52-tigera-ca-bundle") pod "calico-node-rb5s8" (UID: "43736256-5241-46c4-b403-85db6d1d4d52") : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
Nov 01 14:18:46 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:46.124885 3279607 configmap.go:197] Couldn't get configMap kube-system/coredns: failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the conditionNov 01 14:18:46 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:46.124929 3279607 secret.go:192] Couldn't get secret calico-system/node-certs: failed to sync secret cache: timed out waiting for the condition
Nov 01 14:18:46 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:46.125014 3279607 nestedpendingoperations.go:348] Operation for "{volumeName:kubernetes.io/configmap/08f1a4fd-92c5-48fc-a299-636a4f0a469a-config-volume podName:08f1a4fd-92c5-48fc-a299-636a4f0a469a nodeName:}" failed. No retries permitted until 2023-11-01 14:18:46.624972044 +0530 IST m=+3.133808093 (durationBeforeRetry 500ms). Error: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "config-volume" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/configmap/08f1a4fd-92c5-48fc-a299-636a4f0a469a-config-volume") pod "coredns-5fcc5bdd47-8llkc" (UID: "08f1a4fd-92c5-48fc-a299-636a4f0a469a") : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition
Nov 01 14:18:46 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 kubelet[3279607]: E1101 14:18:46.125058 3279607 nestedpendingoperations.go:348] Operation for "{volumeName:kubernetes.io/secret/43736256-5241-46c4-b403-85db6d1d4d52-node-certs podName:43736256-5241-46c4-b403-85db6d1d4d52 nodeName:}" failed. No retries permitted until 2023-11-01 14:18:46.625034355 +0530 IST m=+3.133870397 (durationBeforeRetry 500ms). Error: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "node-certs" (UniqueName: "kubernetes.io/secret/43736256-5241-46c4-b403-85db6d1d4d52-node-certs") pod "calico-node-rb5s8" (UID: "43736256-5241-46c4-b403-85db6d1d4d52") : failed to sync secret cache: timed out waiting for the condition
```

• sudo journalctl -u containerd -f

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2022-04-22 10:32:53 IST. --
Oct 13 00:13:20 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: time="2023-10-13T00:13:20.769518216+05:30" level=info msg="RemovePodSandbox for \"ea81a51660843963fda52520e4d5834bb065e8bc6b48d7350fea5ed462066936\""
Oct 13 00:13:20 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: time="2023-10-13T00:13:20.769565086+05:30" level=info msg="Forcibly stopping sandbox \"ea81a51660843963fda52520e4d5834bb065e8bc6b48d7350fea5ed462066936\""
Oct 13 00:13:20 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: time="2023-10-13T00:13:20.769696525+05:30" level=info msg="TearDown network for sandbox \"ea81a51660843963fda52520e4d5834bb065e8bc6b48d7350fea5ed462066936\" successfully"
Oct 13 00:13:20 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: time="2023-10-13T00:13:20.852087515+05:30" level=info msg="RemovePodSandbox \"ea81a51660843963fda52520e4d5834bb065e8bc6b48d7350fea5ed462066936\" returns successfully"
Nov 01 12:16:31 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: time="2023-11-01T12:16:31.730407989+05:30" level=info msg="No cni config template is specified, wait for other system components to drop the config."
Nov 01 14:18:43 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: time="2023-11-01T14:18:43.710560884+05:30" level=info msg="No cni config template is specified, wait for other system components to drop the config."
Nov 01 14:43:42 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: E1101 14:43:42.533234     828 exec.go:87] error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "845f8446d19b7636bb87b001b881ce7b1f07dc372e61b542dd316605313e5bff": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
Nov 01 14:44:30 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: time="2023-11-01T14:44:30.136995113+05:30" level=info msg="Container exec \"b7fb9daf0322fbdbe4facb31c3d18fdd44d4c6402dc7733dbf5b2c4d659dcb72\" stdin closed"
Nov 01 14:44:30 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: E1101 14:44:30.288136     828 exec.go:87] error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "89067c1007468b006bc9b8d86b446ebbd04438025dd42cd90828123dc1a688b7": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "powershell": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
Nov 01 14:44:30 IN-DT-DCKR-LDR1 containerd[828]: E1101 14:44:30.419019     828 exec.go:87] error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "370d225ba5a9bc40bdc43040b1eda910fe278bd0bf5174682a94bc63a3be18ce": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "cmd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find the error in either

```
sudo journalctl -u kubelet -f
```

or

```
sudo journalctl -u containerd -f
```

My guess would be that you have SystemdCgroup set to false in /etc/containerd/config.toml

Set it to true on all nodes and restart containerd

```
SystemdCgroup = true
```

when you dont have the file yet, create it

`containerd config default > /etc/containerd/config.toml`

then set SystemdCgroup to true and restart containerd

Comment: thank you,

I checked the journalctl and found that there is some error related to 'configmap cache sync'. I've added the output of both the command in the question, do you have any idea about the same?
Also regarding, config.toml file, there is no such file in my system,

Comment: edited the answer to create congig.toml. you are using calico for CNI, try use flannel if the containerd config solution does not work. flannel is easier to begin with but it lacks some features